# replace special characters with % in batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-prompt

Can anyone help how to replace a string which contains special character like space,(,-,) etc.
Lets say i have a string:

```
str=A Room Has (1 level) - (2 - leve) Rooms

Output string should be like:

str=A%Room%Has%%1%level%%%%2%%%leve%%Rooms
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this :

```
@echo off
set "str=A Room Has (1 level) - (2 - leve) Rooms"
echo Before string substitution :   %str%
pause
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "str=!str:-=%%!"
set "str=!str:(=%%!"
set "str=!str:)=%%!"
set "str=!str: =%%!"
Color 0A
echo After string substitution  :   !str!
pause
```

Answer (score 4):

This should work:

```
set "str=A Room Has (1 level) - (2 - leve) Rooms"
set "str=!str:-=%%!"
set "str=!str:(=%%!"
set "str=!str:)=%%!"
set "str=!str: =%%!"
```